# HP Mini 210 -> Touchpad doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, netbook

Specifically, I can neither click nor right-click by using the the touch pad. The touch pad has buttons built-into it, which is why it probably doesn't work by default.

If you followed my previous post, I switched to ubuntu to get wireless working on this netbook (which it does, yay), but now I can't right click. Lovely.

Any suggesions? I installed gsynaptics and enabled SHMConfig, but that didn't do any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fix, check out the link below.....I Love My Mini

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1388164&page=2

Answer (score 1):

Looked around, and there is no solution so far. (Yeah, then maybe this is not a proper answer for you.) However, you could try out a Fedora LiveCD for example since it comes with newer softwares. Guess they fixed this issue. But this is really just an idea. (Install it, and do a FULL upgrade. Since they don't do things like Ubuntu, they *do* update stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

http://greendevnet.blogspot.com/2009/10/ubuntu-910-karmic-koala-no-touchpad.html

Is in in German and related to a different model, but a thread about the mini 210 says that it works for the hp mini 210, too.

Answer (score -1):

```
$su
# echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe.conf
# reboot
```

That should work.